# Disabling the internal microphone of a Laptop

Tags: laptop, audio, microphone

My laptop is an Alienware m5500 with Windows Vista 32 Bit and it has a built-in mic. The issue with this is that I have an external mic that I need to use.

Whenever I try to use Skype or Ventrilo it just picks up the sound from the Internal microphone not the one I have plugged into the jack.

It does not do this however with a USB microphone because this creates a separate sound channel (I think that's what it's called). I'm looking for a way to separate the two microphone channels to external and internal or completely disable the internal.

Comment: Which operating system?

Comment: Windows Vista x32

Comment: Disable it in Device Manager

Comment: Then I can't use my external microphone.

Comment: USB mic will be a different piece of hardware, internal mic can be disabled separately.

Comment: I'm not asking about how to get a USB mic to work, I have that working. I'm asking how to get an external 3.5mm Microphone Jack microphone to work with the Internal Mic being disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You can always choose the default input audio device from `Control panel > Sound` settings. And application like skype also has separate settings for that too. Use them to choose which input device you want to use.

Comment: You can't do that because they are classified as the same sound channel so they don't show up separately.

Comment: THats strange. But the internal mic would be listed in sound settings, under recording devices. You can try disabling it, then connect the external mic and see if that helps.

Comment: And external mic should have its own entry in device list. Are you sure it is being detected?

Comment: No I'm not sure it is being detected because Realtek doesn't notify me that I plugged something into the jack like it does with Headphones.

Comment: Right click on system tray icon of Realtec > `Sound Manager`. Once the window is open, you can see images of two ports at bottom of the window. Green for headphone and pink for mic. Now plug in your mic keeping the window open. If your device is detected, the window will show the settings for Mic and the pink port will lit up. Check it out.